# suma y media de dos columnas en postgres

Tags: postgresql

Buenos días tengo una base de datos en la cual almaceno alumnos y notas.
Tengo las notas del primer examen y del segundo examen y tengo una tercera columna vacia en la que quiero almacenar dichas notas.

Estoy intentando con select para simularlo pero no me saca la media de la suma de las dos columnas:

```
select nombre, avg(primerexamen+segundoexamen) as media  from dl.modulo1 group by nombre;
```

Si alguien puede echarme una mano a sacar esa operación.

Tengo pensado hacer un insert después con la operación indicándole que tiene que guardarlo en la columna notaTrimeste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para calcular esta media, tendrías que calcular primero la de una y luego la de la otra:

```
select nombre, avg(primerexamen), abg(segundoexamen)  from dl.modulo1 group by nombre;
```

Pero esto te lo va a devolver en dos columnas, por lo que podrías hacer una simple ecuación para calcular la media:

```
select nombre, (avg(primerexamen) + abg(segundoexamen)) / 2 as Media from dl.modulo1 group by nombre;
```

De esta manera debería de funcionarte correctamente.

Espero tu respuesta.